# Removing the "s" in HTTPS

Tags: html, http, https

I recently had a friend of mine ask me if I could do some basic security checks on his website. The URL is along the lines of `https://www.example.com` however after removing the "s" at the end of the "https" the site simply redirects me to `www.example.com`. Before I supply him with false information I am assuming that this is a huge vulnerability - seeing that he deals with credit card information of his clients. Am I over-hyping it? How big of an issue is this?

The site should ideally send an error or redirect to the HTTPS version of the site. Am I right with my thinking?
Thanks

Comment: Not necessarily. Some sites often works on HTTP... until it is time to do something sensitive (login, or payment). But beyond that, HTTP version usually works. If HTTP works but not intended, you can ask your friend to do a redirect. It is possible to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, or even set HSTS to ensure the site is always accessed via HTTPS. So in the end it really whether it is by design, or it is a mistake.

Comment: On the other hand, such redirects are very easy to strip unless HSTS is used. These days – if the site deals with payments _at all_, it should use it to enforce HTTPS everywhere.

Comment: `Before I supply him with false information I am assuming that this is a huge vulnerability` - why are you doing this check ? It depends on how it's being redirected!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any website handling sensitive information should run on HTTPS. Running on HTTP is risky. So, you are right, it should redirect to HTTPS automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> after removing the "s" at the end of the "https" the site simply redirects me to "www.example.com"

Manually removing the "s" means you're **explicitly visiting `http://www.example.com` (i.e. the non-SSL version) yourself**.

Now what happens is most browsers hide the `http://` part in the address bar for readability (`http://` is just techno clutter to most common folks). So it just doesn't display the `http://` in front of the URL but it's really still there.

So it's actually not redirecting you anywhere. In fact there is no such thing as redirecting to `www.example.com` without a protocol prefix like `http://`. If you see `www.example.com` in the address bar and select all + copy + paste, you will see the `http://` prefix is still there. And if you type `www.example.com` manually without any protocol prefix, your browser will automatically assume an implicit `http://` prefix.

As for the vulnerability part: any site dealing with sensitive information (or maybe just any site in general, depending on how paranoid you are) should enforce SSL, thus not even support or allow to be visited through `http://`, only `https://`.

Since the coming of [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) everybody can use SSL on their website for free. So basically there's no reason *not* to use SSL anymore.

Personally I use Let's Encrypt everywhere, on every single website I host or manage. And I make sure that any non-SSL visits (i.e. whenever someone visits the page with `http://` instead of `https://`) are automatically redirected to the corresponding `https://` URL.

There's different ways to do this, but probably the easiest way is putting a file called `.htaccess` in your `public_html/` dir with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

What this does is it directs any request that does not use SSL, to the same URL with SSL.

Comment: Let me give you a scenario 'cause I am still trying to wrap my head around the potential danger. Imagine there is an attacker trying to steal sensitive information and a user that is typing in his/her credit card details. Does the user have to accidentally stumble upon the HTTP Url in order to be in danger? Seeing as the site has both HTTP and HTTPS, is there a way the hacker can get sensitive information simply due to the presence of the HTTP version of the site? I keep getting warning messages from my browser, but those warnings are all irrelevant if I simply stay on the HTTPS version right?

Comment: @JakeGould I don't, that's why I said *probably*. In most regular hosting situations, this will be likely the case though.

Comment: @Argentum The user would have to be visiting the website through HTTP instead of HTTPS, and then enter sensitive information, while someone else is packet sniffing or man-in-the-middle'ing or otherwise intercepting the traffic, in order to be at risk. One way for this to happen is if the user accidentally stumbles upon an HTTP url, yes. However this is ONLY if the site even allows entering such sensitive information though non-HTTPS in the first place. Hence my recommendation: just *always* enforce HTTPS. You say "seeing as the site has both HTTP and HTTPS", well simply disable the HTTP part.

Comment: Certbot from Let's Encrypt can generate a cert, install it, and configure your server to redirect to HTTPS.